# New skinned mesh animation system in three.js r73

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

i am testing the new skinned mesh animation system in three.js (examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending) r73 using the excellent tips here (http://www.yomotsu.net/blog/2015/10/31/three-r73-anim.html) with my own model--All tests are fine when viewed in Blender (v2.76) and when exported with THREE.js(r73)Exporter my mesh animates OK in browser BUT mesh has unlikely holes no matter how many variations on export parameters i try (checked normals in Blender and they are fine)[this image show the random holes in the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfK56.png)
any suggestions i am most grateful...

Comment: You checked those vertices doesnt have a weight of 0?

Comment: omg-thanks! --i parented armature/actions to different mesh and Blender crated new, 'empty' vertex groups i didn't catch.!